# Locking access to table while updating a row

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot with JPA (older version: starter parent is 1.4.4). I have a table with a list of transactions (-1, +10, -5 and so on). This transactions affect the balance of a user.
I don't have a field for balance in my user, i retrieve the last transaction, and get the balance computed in that row. The problems are:

- concurrent access to table (for example, if i have the same user running parallel requests, the balance is probably fetched while someone is actually inserting a new row)
- it's very slow if i try to add locking to the table

What are your suggestions?
Thanks

I tried locking the table, with no results whatsoever.

Comment: Add balance to account / user level as locking that balance value will ensure that concurrent transactions have to wait for one another

Comment: @Shadow that's what i thought too. Do i store the remainingBalance inside the transactions table?

Comment: It depends on your business requirements. Storing balance after every transaction can help you analysing trends in balances without the need of recalculating those balances based on transactional values. if you do not have such need, then you should not store balances on transaction level.

Comment: Look up 'database transactions' and `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` which has to be done within a db transaction. The latter locks a row-range rather than the table. Note that the rows you select don't have to be updated, it just guarantees that no other db transaction can do the same SELECT ... FOR UPDATE until your transaction is done. Anything you write based on data you read should also be done in the same db transaction.